# kafka connection error: Failed to resolve, Connection refused

Tags: python, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Zookeeper and kafka are running using

> docker compose up -d

```
---
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: broker
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
```

I have a producer file running locally having
`p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})`

The consumer would be running via docker

```
FROM python:3.9.5-alpine3.14

RUN apk update \
    && /sbin/apk add --no-cache --virtual .deps gcc musl-dev \
    && /usr/local/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir black==19.10b0 \
    && /sbin/apk del --no-cache .deps \
    && apk add --no-cache git \
    && apk add --update py-pip \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add linux-headers \
    && apk add --no-cache cargo python3-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev g++ make \
    && apk add --no-cache librdkafka-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers \
    && pip install Pillow
    
COPY /requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD [ "python3", "consumer.py" ]
```

consumer.py has code:

```
c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'broker:9092',
    'group.id': 'consumer-group-a',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})
```

I'm trying not to edit the hosts file.
`Failed to resolve 'broker:9092': Name or service not known` and `Connection refused`. I've mainly encountered these 2 errors while trying to run this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the Python service in the same compose file such that it is part of the same Docker network where `broker` DNS name can be resolved.

e.g.

```
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: ./app/  # folder with Dockerfile
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092  # don't hardcode this in your code

  zookeeper:
     ...
  broker:
     ...
```

Note: Your consumer may try to connect before Kafka is actually running, so you should add some sleep duration.

Otherwise, use `docker network ls`, find which network is hosting Kafka and Zookeper, then use `docker run --network <name> your-python-app`